# Handling multiple object types in a large dataset to build a better ML model

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-cleaning, visualization

I have a dataset with multiple object data_types. From the dataset, most of them were made into categorical features (Using One-hot encoding as well). But few of them have object data types with 6M rows. How to deal with those?
I tried using `value_counts()` method but the counts passed beyond 10K. What would be the best option to handle these data of multiple features?

Comment: What are the names of those features?

Comment: @RaymondKwok Its number as an example ```INC0000045```.